# Best way to connect multiple controllers to a PC

Tags: steam, pc, controllers, hardware

I was considering building a LAN PC (e.g. a Mini ITX portable build) to bring around to my friends houses.

I remember last time I tried to play two player Castle Crashers on Steam, we had a problem where controllers would not connect correctly. 
When my friend pressed `A` it would make my character jump.

**Question:**

Is it possible to connect multiple controllers to a PC? If so, what tool did you use? Would it work with old console emulators (like Nintendo 64 / etc.)? Do all the controllers have to be of the same type? (e.g. all Xbox controllers)

Comment: I know emulators like project 64 and dolphin do support multiple controllers. In the controller settings you can basically set which physical controller corresponds to the emulator controller. I did have to use special connectors to use the original 64 and game cube controllers with my PC but it did let me use 4 at once.

Comment: Not sure what's up with Castle Crashers, but your computer should recognize each controller as an independent device.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to connect **up to 4 controllers** to your computer without any issues.

I personnaly connect my Xbox 360 and DualShock V2 controllers at the same time to play Street Fighter V locally and have never ran into any problems. I'm guessing the issue you encountered was likely linked to the game itself and not Steam.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the type of controllers, but generally you can plug in as many as you would like to a modern Windows 10 computer. Adding your emulators to Steam and launching them through its "big picture mode" will also allow you to configure the controller's buttons to act differently for all, or for specific programs/emulators/games you launch from it. This lets you use something strange such as an old Logitech flightstick with a game or emulator that is expecting a different sort of controller such as the incredibly common Xbox 360/Xbox One gamepad.

Knowing what specific type of controllers you're using could help folks flesh out their answers more specifically to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Windows maximum for all joysticks put together is 8 axis and 32 buttons in total. If for example each joystick has 2 axis then you can have 4 joysticks in total. There is no way around this unless the application you are running (game etc) can accept other kind of joystick control signals e.g. through the network.